# jQuery loop animations on same object at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to animate the same object with different speeds and starting at the same time?

```
function loop_horiz(direction){
    var d = (direction == 1) ? '+' : '-';
    $('.op').animate({ left: d + '200' },
     4000, function() { loop_horiz(direction * (-1)) });
}

function loop_vert(direction){
    var d = (direction == 1) ? '+' : '-';
    $('.op').animate({ bottom: d + '200' },
    2000, function() { loop_vert(direction * (-1)) });
}

loop_horiz(1);
loop_vert(1)
```

Comment: Did you try? What errors (if any) are you getting?

Comment: @GlauberRocha, it doesn't need 'px', @David, it works, but the animations are queueing. If I set `queue: false`, the animations won't loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally when animating an object with jQuery, the animation is added to the queue for that object. When previous animations have ended, the animation starts running. Your code above does exactly that, animates horizontally, then vertically.

This behavior can be overwritten by the use of the queue option of the animation (set it to false).

```
function loop_horiz(direction) {
    var d = (direction == 1) ? '+' : '-';
    $('.op').animate({
        left: d + '200'
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 4000,
        done: function () {
            loop_horiz(direction * (-1))
        }
    });
}

function loop_vert(direction) {
    var d = (direction == 1) ? '+' : '-';
    $('.op').animate({      
        bottom: d + '200'
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 2000,
        done: function () {
            loop_vert(direction * (-1))
        }
    });

}

loop_horiz(1);
loop_vert(1)
```

Another (uglier) possibility is to merge the animations, but it would require you to split the horizontal animation in two for half the distance running over 2s.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Even better, with queue as string you can add the animations to different queues. 
Same code as above, but using different queues for vertical and horizontal animation:

```
function loop_horiz(direction) {
    var d = (direction == 1) ? '+' : '-';
    $('.op').animate({
        left: d + '200'
    }, {
        queue: 'horizontal',
        duration: 4000,
        done: function () {
            loop_horiz(direction * (-1))
        }
    }).dequeue('horizontal');
}

function loop_vert(direction) {
    var d = (direction == 1) ? '+' : '-';
    $('.op').animate({
        bottom: d + '200'
    }, {
        queue: 'vertical',
        duration: 2000,
        done: function () {
            loop_vert(direction * (-1))
        }
    }).dequeue('vertical');

}

loop_horiz(1);
loop_vert(1)
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Uewzc/1/

Comment: As I responded in an earlier comment, setting the queue to false, stops the loop. Il will try to split the horizontal animation though

Comment: I think I may have put the queue in the wrong place. I've put the queue and duration in the second parameter and the callback function in the third. So the correct form is that the queue, duration and callback all must be in the second parameter. Thanks!

Comment: There are two forms of calling the animate method, one with two objects as parameters (where you can specify the queue) and another one with 1-4 parameters. You probably had them confused. The documentation is pretty clear though, check it when you have doubts!